# Proof of l'Hôpital's rule, g'(0)=0

Tags: calculus, limits

**l'Hôpital's rule for limits where $\mathbf{x\to 0}$.** Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous and differentiable in a neighborhood of $x=0$. Then, if 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) =0\,,$$ 
the following simplification can be made: 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\,,$$
provided that the limit in the right-hand side exists.

**Problem.** The proof in my textbook assumes that $g'(0)\neq 0$. In many cases, however, that is not true, but the theorem can still be used. So somehow there must be a way to prove the theorem without this, or with some weaker requirement.

**Failed attempt.** Rewrite with Maclaurin's formula:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(0)+f'(\xi)x}{g(0)+g'(\zeta)x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0+f'(\xi)x}{0+g'(\zeta)x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\zeta)}\,,$$
where $\xi$ and $\zeta$ are somewhere between 0 and $x$. When $x\to 0$, both $\xi$ and $\zeta$ go to zero, but when $g'(0)=0$, as some helpful people concluded [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584609/limit-of-strange-function-composition), that doesn't necessarily mean that last limit is equal to $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)/g'(x)$.

Is this a dead end, or can I do something to make this work? Or are there any other proof methods that could be understood with basic calculus skills?

Comment: check "Proof of L'Hospital's Rule" in blog post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-4.html Your second approach is near to the actual proof. The actual proof ensures that you can find $p, q$ with $p = q$. Also the limitation $g'(x) \neq 0$ is obvious because if $g'(x)$ vanishes then $\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x)/g'(x)$ won't exist.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your textbook assuming $g'(x)\not=0$ because if it is equal to $0$, then $g(x)$ is a non-zero constant function. In which case, l'Hôpitals rule doesn't apply.

Comment: Try using rolles theorem

Comment: Clarification: my problem was that the proof in my book only works for $g'(0)\neq 0$, and that is pretty restrictive. For example, that wouldn't allow us to use l'Hôpital on things like $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos (\sin x)}{\sin^2 x}\,.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem with my original approach was that $\xi$ and $\zeta$ might tend to $0$ at different rates. The solution therefore lies in finding a way to rewrite $f(x)/g(x)$ to something like $f'(\xi)/g'(\xi)$ where we have the same $\xi$ both in the numerator and the denominator.

This following proof is based on [this blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-4.html) by Paramanand Singh (recommended in the comments to my original post) and [this text](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/sadun/F11/408N/L'Hopital.pdf) by Lorenzo Sadun. The key in both of their proofs is to extend the mean value theorem in the following way:

> **Cauchy's mean value theorem.** Let $f$ and $g$ be real-valued functions that are continious on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Then there exists some $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that $$f'(\xi)\cdot [g(b)-g(a)]=g'(\xi)\cdot [f(b)-f(a)]\,.$$

*Proof.* Very similar to the proof of the usual mean value theorem; just
apply Rolle's theorem (check that it really is applicable!) to 
$$h(x)=[f(x)-f(a)]\cdot[g(b)-g(a)]-[g(x)-g(a)]\cdot [f(b)-f(a)]\,.$$

We are now ready to prove a variation of l'Hôpital's rule, where we don't require $g'(0)\neq 0$ (in fact, we don't even require that $g'(0)$ exists!). Instead we make the much milder assumption that $g'(x)\neq 0$ in some punctured neighborhood around $x=0$.

> **L'Hôpital's rule.**  Let $f$ and $g$ be continious in a neighbourhood of $x=0$, and differentiable in a punctured neighborhood of $x=0$. Suppose that $g'(x)\neq 0$ in some punctured neightborhood of $x=0$, and that $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=0\:\:\text{and}\:\:\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}= L\,.$$ Then $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L\,.$$

*Proof.* Start by noting that we, by the continuity of $f$ and $g$, have
$$f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0\ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ g(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=0\,.$$

We will now show the right-sided limit $$\lim_{x\downarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L.$$ 
Rhe proof for the left-sided version is going to be analogous.

From the premises of the theorem, we note that if we choose $a>0$ sufficiently small, we can make the following three statements hold:

1. $f$ and $g$ are definined and continious on $[0,a]$, and differentiable on $(0,a)$.
2. $g'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in (0,a)$.
3. $g(a)\neq g(0)=0$.Otherwise there would exist some $c\in (0,a)$ such that $g'(c)=0$ by Rolle's theorem, which would contradict statement (2).

Statement (1) gives, by Cauchy's mean value theorem, that
$$f'(\xi)\cdot [g(a)-g(0)] = g'(\xi)\cdot [f(a)-f(0)]$$ 
for some $\xi\in (0,a)$. With $f(0)=g(0)=0$ this means that
$$f'(\xi)\cdot g(a) = g'(\xi)\cdot f(a)\,,$$
which we, by statement (2) och (3) can be rewritten as 
$$\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}=\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}\,.$$

We will now apply this to the the right-sided limit that we are trying to derive. Since $x$ can be assumed to be arbitrarily small and positive as $x\downarrow 0$, we can write 
$$\lim_{x\downarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\downarrow 0} \frac{f'(\xi(x))}{g'(\xi(x))},$$
for some $\xi(x)\in (0,x)$, for all suffciently small $x$. By an easy exersise in the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition of a limit (we shouldn't just blindly make the substitution $t=\xi(x)$ because of the risk of running into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919798/the-limit-of-composition-of-two-functions) mess), we can now show that $$\lim_{x\downarrow 0} \frac{f'(\xi(x))}{g'(\xi(x))} =\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}=L\,.$$
This gives us the desried right-sided limit:
$$\lim_{x\downarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= L\,.$$

Now reapeat the argument above with with left-sided neighbourhoods of $x=0$ instead of right-sided ones, to show that
$$\lim_{x\uparrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= L\,.$$
This concludes the proof.

Comment: By the way there is no risk of "running into this mess" if we use the substitution $t=\xi(x) $. The important point is that limit of $f'/g'$ exists finitely or infinitely. The risk you mention appears only when the limit of $f'/g'$ does not exist because in that case it may happen that for some $\xi(x) $ the limit $f'(\xi(x)) /g'(\xi(x)) $ may exist. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2499411/72031) for a concrete example.

Comment: And I am glad that my blog post is useful to someone. +1 for your answer.

Comment: I just ran into another proof following this idea, and a very nice, general formulation of l'Hôpital's rule in this article by A.E. Taylor from 1952: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2307183