# Prove f is continuous and that f'(0) DNE

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x\sin(1/x)  & : \text{if }x \neq 0 \\
0 & : \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}$$

I have to show that f is continuous. I know that it's continuous when x doesn't equal 0 since f is a composition of continuous functions. But how do I show that it is continuous when x=0?

And then to show that f'(0) DNE, do I just need to take the derivative of the function and then plug in 0 for x?

Thank you!

Comment: When $x$ is near zero, $f$ is small. Thus it's continuous. Use this idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (replacing $x$ by $1/y$)
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(1/x) = \lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y}.
$$
Now, use that $\sin$ is a bounded function.

Comment: How or why do those equal each other?

Comment: I edited it to make this clearer. Actually, you don't need this identity. Just use that the sine function is bounded. So, it cannot tend to infinity when $x$ tends to zero.

Comment: A remark: We can substitute here beacuse as y goes infinity, $\dfrac{1}{y}$ approaches 0, but is never zero. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919798/the-limit-of-composition-of-two-functions

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**: a function $f$ is continuous at $a$ when it has a limit there. That is, when $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ is well-defined. In this case, since you already know that the function is continuous away from zero, you need to consider $a=0$ (i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x\sin(1/x)$).

**Hint 2**: take the derivative of $x\mapsto x\sin(1/x)$. What happens to this derivative at zero?

Comment: I don't think Hint 2 works in the way you want it. The derivative at zero is a special case: when we use standard differentiation, we are implicitly assuming that the function is defined the same way throughout a neighborhood. The fact that it is piecewise might make us worry a little bit.